# Не могу подключить dll на C# в проект Visual Studio

Tags: dll

Как добавить в проект на C# dll?

Сама dll лежит в отдельной папке, а в Обозревателе решений в пункте Ссылки в вызываемом контекстном меню отсутствует пункт на Добавление ссылки.

Проект делается в Unity, код редактирую в Visual Studio 2022. Может быть в последней версии студии иначе подключаются dll?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не может такого быть. В новой версии Студии всё нормально подключается. Вы могли встать не на тот пункт в References - там же есть reference разных типов, не только DLL. но и внешние ресурсы, сервисы и т.п. И это всё - в разделе References. Хотите - запостите картинку с открытым разделом

Comment: Я вызываю контекстное меню при нажатии на Ссылки - никакого другого подобного пункта там нет. Может быть дело в версии целевой платформы .NET 6?

Comment: Хм. Сейчас повторю эксперимент у себя... А project какого типа? DLL?

Comment: Проект на Unity - полноценное приложение. Но к нему надо поключить dll. Я тут Unity осваиваю по пособиям 3-4 летней давности, а в них некоторый функционал проекта вынесен в сторонние dll. У меня подозрение, что вся проблема не в Visual Studio, а в целевой платформе проекта .NET 6. И я не могу найти, как в ней подключать dll

Comment: я повторил эксперимент, и у меня всё выглядит так, как я и предполагал. Это значит, что я Вас как то не так понял - не понял, что именно Вы делаете. Может, Вым еще пару скриншотов в вопрос доьавить? Короче, подсказка такая,: от версии Студии ничего не зависит

Comment: я готов содержательно поговорить про unity, потому что сам нахожусь в таком же положении. Вообще, подозрение - может быть правильным, сейчас погуглю

Comment: Навскидку нашел только вот такую, довольно старую статью: https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/563060/ В общем. непонятно. Ждем, когда придёт какой то настоящий знаток и объяснит! :-)

Comment: Спасибо. Насчёт юнити, я сейчас вспоминаю, где в ней остановился 3 месяца назад. Но вот без подключения dll дело дальше у меня не сдвинется. Я вспомнил, что и 3 месяца назад, когда я активно начал Юнити осваивать, тоже были траблы с написанием кода в Студии из-за новой платформы .NET 6, где всё выглядит иначе